# how to know the column data type in sql by passing attribute name from swings

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I want to know the column data type in sql by passing attribute name from swings

Here is the detailed explanation with ex:

```
create table student(rollnumber varchar2(15),name varchar2(40));
```

from the front end GUI application(swings), I retrieve column names of student table by passing student as an argument and again I pass column names(rollnumbers,name) as arguments, here I want example code(in java) for to know  data type of that particular column name(rollnumber,student),
please give me guidance for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public String getColumnType(Connection conn, String columnName)
        throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT "
            + columnName + " FROM student")) {
        return ps.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(1);
    }
}
```

For more details see [ResultSetMetaData documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html).

Comment: thank you ...sir ,,if i have any doubts i will contact your profile ...is it ok for you?